Reason for wall discoloration/deterioration
My sister recently noticed the following discoloration/deterioration on her wall:


The construction company for the house came by to take a look at it and determined that this is indeed unusual for a wall this new (about 3 years) and it should probably be looked at.
So far so good, it seems they want to remove a chunk of the wall to check if the source is within the walls. This kinda freaks my sister out and as she saw one of the neighborhood cats peeing against it a few times she first wanted to make sure that isn't the reason.
She tried looking at it with a cheapish blacklight:

We think you can see a very slight blacklight effect, mostly at the borders, but we feel if cat pee is the main reason you should be able to see the effect on the entire region. Also if it is indeed cat pee, shouldn't it have at least dripped down a bit on the lower part of the wall?
We'd be grateful if someone could rule out cat pee, as were not even sure if it could cause an effect like this, or suggest another test to check if thats the reason.

This is just an educated guess, but I would blame the cat, or a dog. There is no indication of some great structural issue.

I doubt it's animal-generated. I see slight separations at the corner in the first picture that appear to indicate pressure from inside the wall.

it seems they want to remove a chunk of the wall to check if the source is within the walls. This kinda freaks my sister out

They built the house. They, presumably, are not of the opinion that it's cat pee if they want to take a look inside the wall. They are presumably capable of opening the wall they built and repairing the wall after opening it. I don't see any reason to be "freaked out" about that. Kind of nice to have a responsible builder, really.
